# Cloudfront + Cognito + API-Gateway Authorization cache

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, amazon-cloudfront

In order to make cloudfront + cognito + api-gateway work together, I have to whitelist the `Authorization`-header in the cloudfront-behavior settings. This also means that this part will be cached - which is generally fine, because I want the cloudfront cache to be user-specific.

What bugs me is that the `Authorization`-header (which basically is `getIdToken().getJwtToken()`) expires every hour resulting in creating a new cache-entry. Meaning: **Every hour the cache for every user is invalid.**

My take on that was to get rid of the `Authorization` in the cache and instead use the `sub`-entry, which is something like a user-id.
However, I really don't know how to achieve this (When removing Authorization from the whitelist, the request is unauthorized).

Or is there another way to keep user-specific content in the cache for longer that 1 hour.

Comment: quick question: when you whitelist a header in CloudFront, cloudfront keeps and serve cached response based on it's value and if the token has changed and user is coming with new token the value has changed and it'll be a miss and request will go to origin.

Comment: I think you can write a lambda viewer function to read authorization header and contact api gateway directly ?

Comment: you're exactly right. so, how do I structure this viewer-function? do you have an example?